# Wordpress wp_login hook not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My code does not seem to run upon logging in using the 'wp_login' hook. The code is meant to update last logged in date. This is my code

```
        function get_current_time($user) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $time =  time();
        update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time );
        }
        add_action('wp_login', 'get_current_time', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is partly incorrect.

Try this:

```
function get_current_time( $user_login, $user ) {
    $time =  time();
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_last_login', $time);
}
add_action('wp_login', 'get_current_time', 10, 2);
```

Codex reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login